# How do I make this loop work and be as efficient as possible?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

I have a heap of repetition and I know I can make this more efficient but haven't done much 'for loops' before.

I have begun the loop below, but I'm not even sure if I'm passing 'i' correctly.

```
for (int i=0; i<=6; i++) {
 var bg(i) = $('.section('+ i +') .container').css("background-image");
 var bg2 = $('.section(2) .container').css("background-image");
 var bg3 = $('.section(3) .container').css("background-image");
 var bg4 = $('.section(4) .container').css("background-image");
 var bg5 = $('.section(5) .container').css("background-image");
 var bg6 = $('.section(6) .container').css("background-image");

 $("#sectionImage1 img").hover(function(){  
    $('.section(1) .container').addClass('roll1');
 }, function(){
    $('.section(1) .container').removeClass('roll1');
    $('.section(1) .container').css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + bg1 + ')'
    });
 });

 $("#sectionImage2 img").hover(function(){  
    $('.section(2) .container').addClass('roll2');
 }, function(){
    $('.section(2) .container').removeClass('roll2');
    $('.section(2) .container').css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + bg2 + ')'
    });
 })
 //... and so on, done 6 times (never more).
}
```

Comment: `int` in **JS** ? One could provide better solution if you clearly mention your requirement !

Comment: I don't know how to approach it, hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
function bindHover( counter )
{
 var bg  = $('.section('+ counter +') .container').css("background-image");
 $("#sectionImage"+ counter +" img").hover(function(){  
    $('.section('+ counter +') .container').addClass('roll'+ counter +'');
 }, function(){
    $('.section('+ counter +') .container').removeClass('roll'+ counter +'');
    $('.section('+ counter +') .container').css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + bg + ')'
    });
 });
}
```

and then call it in the for loop

Comment: How do I pass the 'i', for eg, in the for loop to the function?

Comment: @RebeccaO'Sullivan for (int i=0; i<=6; i++){  bindHover( i ); }